# how to use airflow connection as environment variables in python code

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

Does anyone know how to access airflow environment variable using AIRFLOW_CONN_ and use in the python code. I know we can use hook to get the password, but have been trying to use AIRFLOW_CONN in my python to connect to the database. I have saved the connection in Airflow UI and in the docs, they mentioned to use AIRFLOW_CONN_ prefix to the conn_id to use. I used it in my python code using os.environ['AIRFLOW_CONN_REDSHIFT'], but it does not identify the environment variable. Please help.

Comment: Do you mean to save connection object as environment variables?

Comment: I have saved the connection object in Airflow UI. Now I want to use them in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Saving the connection to database and setting an `AIRFLOW_CONN_` environment variable are two different ways to add a connection. You should only choose one way, unless you want them stored under connection ids.

Assuming you are running your python code through an operator like `PythonOperator`, you should be able to fetch your connection just like the [BaseHook](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/base_hook.py#L43-L64) does.

Stored in database:

```
@classmethod
def _get_connections_from_db(cls, conn_id):
    session = settings.Session()
    db = (
        session.query(Connection)
        .filter(Connection.conn_id == conn_id)
        .all()
    )
    session.expunge_all()
    session.close()
    if not db:
        raise AirflowException(
            "The conn_id `{0}` isn't defined".format(conn_id))
    return db
```

Stored in environment variable:

```
@classmethod
def _get_connection_from_env(cls, conn_id):
    environment_uri = os.environ.get(CONN_ENV_PREFIX + conn_id.upper())
    conn = None
    if environment_uri:
        conn = Connection(conn_id=conn_id, uri=environment_uri)
    return conn
```

Although I would recommend fetching it via a hook to avoid duplicating this code!